# What are the twelve items I need to collect for the Santa's Little Helper challenge?

Tags: hitman-2016

One of the challenges in the special "Holiday Hoarders" mission in Hitman is named "Santa's Little Helper". The description is as follows:

> - Collect all 12 items the burglars want to steal, before they do.
> - Do not kill the targets before collecting the items.

What items are Harry and Marv actually after? I've looked around the level but nothing has stood out to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this [Steam guide](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=817655520), here is the list of the different items Harry and Marv are looking for and their locations:

> **Items taken by Harry**:
>
> 1. Firework Remote (Stage Crew area on the table, 1st floor).
> 2. Circumcision Knife (Room with the lone Auction Staff, in a map box near the window, 1st floor).
> 3. Sabre (Attic nearby the security zone, 2nd floor).
> 4. Microphone (Attic in an intersection with 2 guards at the window, 2nd floor).
> 5. Cowboy Bust (Attic inside the "Attic" spawn location on a table, 2nd floor).
> 6. Bust (Attic nearby security zone on the table with the monitory, 2nd floor).
>
> **Items taken by Marv**:
>
> 1. Coconut (Canteen, underground).
> 2. Apricot (Kitchen near the fireplace, underground).
> 3. Canon Ball (Museum near the stylist area on a table with a boat, ground floor).
> 4. Toy Tank (In the room with the blogger that needs the camera lens next to the 2 stylists talking, ground floor).
> 5. Battle Axe (On the big table at the party, ground floor).
> 6. Shuriken (In the hallway near the tech crew guy talking to the model, on a cloth rack, ground floor).